# Are there prohibitions of work on chol hamoed at the biblical level?

Tags: chol-hamoed

Some categories of  melacha are permitted on chol hamoed. Are there any categories of  melacha that are prohibited on  chol hamoed at the  biblical level (d'oraissa)?

Comment: I have edited your question in the hope of clarifying the issue. If I have it wrong, sorry and please roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how we Pasken.

It seems from the Gemera in Chagiga 18a that it's a Biblical prohibition to do [certain] work on Chol HaMo'ed. The Gamara brings about half a dozen verses to prove that.

But Rashi and Tosafot already argue as to whether it's really Biblical or Rabbinic [with a *Asmachta* (hint) on the Torah].